# How to make a fast serve in Grand Slam Tennis for Wii?

Tags: grand-slam-tennis

In Grand Slam Tennis for Wii I make subpar serves, I usually have a speed from nearly 50mph. Computer players and players online get serves with 70-80mph (or even faster). How can I do that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read, as you play through the game in Grand Slam mode, your character learns new skills and gains experience as you beat opponents (see [the game's Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Slam_Tennis)). I imagine the more you win, the faster your serve will become and/or you'll beat a player that will "teach" your character how.

Comment: That's all? To make a serve I swing the Wiimote and not pus a button. And the game supports WiiMotion Plus. All that input doesn't matter in the end?

Comment: There may some mechanics for an optimal serve. I've read online that good wrist action helps.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This works for me, it may or may not work for you.

Try flicking the wiimote backwards instead of forwards when you serve. I find this gives the quickest wrist action.